# Translate Julia to Python

Tags: python, julia, translation

I have a code written in Julia that I have to translate to Python, is the following one:

```
def descr(x):
    return sum(x ^ 2) / length(x)
```

But I don't know how to translate this line:

```
function waveletdescr(img; maxlevel::Int=2)
```

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to interpret it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: have you tried `maxlevel=2`?

Comment: I don't know why you've added `self` all over the place in the python version.

Comment: @HåkenLid because I want to call two functions that are in the same class. Don't I need them?

Comment: If it's a method, you have to add `self` as the first argument in the method. `def waveletdescr(self, img, maxlevel::Int=2):`.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia you have separate positional parameters and keyword parameters and they are separated by a semicolon - in Python there is no such separation (maybe with exception of `*`and `**` parameter operators). Additionally, in Julia there are types hence your Python line will simply be:

```
def waveletdescr(img, maxlevel=2):
```

Additionally, when using your function in Python make sure that `img` and `v` are an numpy arrays (I guess they are but normally one would `import numpy as np` so in your code I would rather expect `np.zeros` that `zeros`)

Comment: Ok!! Thank you so much for your answer:) It really helped me!